# Сравнить два разных ассоциативных массива в php?

Tags: php

Есть два массива:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [y] => 67
            [product_id] => 0
            [product_type] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [y] => 30
            [product_id] => 3
            [product_type] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [y] => 17
            [product_id] => 2
            [product_type] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [y] => 23
            [product_id] => 1
            [product_type] => 2
        )

)
```

Второй массив

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 1
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 2
            [id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 3
            [id] => 2
        )

)
```

Мне нужно проверять, если совпадает [product_id] первого массива с [id] второго массива, то в первый массив добавлять [type] => [id][title] - второго массива.

Я это делаю так:
 1. Считаю длину массива 2.
 2. Запускаю for пока $i < Длинны массива 2
 3. Сравниваю $i[product_id] и $i[id]
 4. Если совпадает, то записываю значение.
Это работает, но срабатывает только 3 раза, потому что длинна второго массива 3, а первый больше, потому всё не просчитывает.
Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: имеет ли значение, положение элемента в массиве? Т.е. нужно проверять только наличие или еще и совпадение индексов?

Comment: Нужно только чтобы проверялось на совпадения все  [product_id] первого массива с [id] второго массива

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array_walk(
    $array1,
    function (&$item1, $key) use ($array2) { // параметры value, key
        if ($item1['product_id'] == $array2[$key]['id']) {
            $item1['type'] = $array2[$key]['title']
        }
});
```

Функция `array_walk` проходит по массиву $array1 и выполняет функцию, переданную 2-м параметром над элементами массива

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($array1 as $pos => $item)
{
    foreach ($array2 as $title)
    {
        if ($item['product_id'] == $title['id'])
        {
            $array1[$pos]['title'] = $title['title'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($a as $key=>$val){
    foreach($b as $k=>$v['id']){
        if( $val['product_id'] === $v){
            $a[$key]['type'] = $v['title'];       
        }
    }
}
```