# Создать массив из 2-х массивов с добавлением ключей-значений, если значения определенного ключа совпадают

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12314143-8e78-11e8-9107-50480010f12b                
            [cart] => 12187
            [sum] => 1800
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1a6f10cf-8e9d-11e8-9109-f8fc001fe6bb
            [cart] => 23456
            [sum] => 12075
        )
)
```

Массив 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1a6f10cf-8e9d-11e8-9109-f8fc001fe6bb
            [fdemand] => 2018-07-18 13:48:00
            [ldemand] => 2018-07-18 13:48:00
            [sumdemand] => 1
            [avedemand] => 8800
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12314143-8e78-11e8-9107-50480010f12b
            [fdemand] => 2018-07-23 16:52:00
            [ldemand] => 2018-07-23 16:52:00
            [sumdemand] => 1
            [avedemand] => 6500
        )
)
```

Как создать массив из вышеуказанных 2-х массивов, чтобы получилось так.
То есть при совпадении по ключу id все остальные ключи-значения этого элемента из 2-х массивов объединились?

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1a6f10cf-8e9d-11e8-9109-f8fc001fe6bb
                [cart] => 23456
                [sum] => 12075
                [fdemand] => 2018-07-18 13:48:00
                [ldemand] => 2018-07-18 13:48:00
                [sumdemand] => 1
                [avedemand] => 8800
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 12314143-8e78-11e8-9107-50480010f12b
                [cart] => 12187
                [sum] => 1800
                [fdemand] => 2018-07-23 16:52:00
                [ldemand] => 2018-07-23 16:52:00
                [sumdemand] => 1
                [avedemand] => 6500
            )
    )
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Решил свой вопрос без создания нового массива, а дополнением данных из одного массива в другой:

```
foreach ($main as $key=>$val){
    foreach($main1 as $k=>$v){
        if( $val['id'] === $v['id']){
        $main[$key]['fdemand'] = $v['fdemand'];
        $main[$key]['ldemand'] = $v['ldemand'];
        $main[$key]['sumdemand'] = $v['sumdemand'];
        $main[$key]['avedemand'] = $v['avedemand'];

        }
    }
}
```

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526644/304416

Answer (score 0):

```
function massiv_merge($one, $two, $count)
{
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if ($one[$i]['id'] == $two[$i]['id']) {
            $value = array_merge($one[$i], $two[$i]);
        }
        print_r($value);
    }
}
```

Где:
$one - первый массив
$two - второй массив
$count - количество массивов в массиве

Comment: Спасибо. Но есть нюанс. Последовательность id у каждого массива своя. То есть, к примеру, id первого элемента первого массива не совпадает с id первого элемента второго массива.

Comment: @Buziks, то есть необходимо, чтобы ключ id каждого массива был выше всех остальных ключей при выводе?

Comment: Не важно в какой последовательности расположен ключ id чтобы объединить их в один, главное чтобы ключ был объявлен и значения ключа были одинаковы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще рассмотреть вариант без циклов:

```
$tmp = array_combine(array_column($array2, 'id'), $array2);

$result = array_map(function ($item) use ($tmp) {
    if (isset($tmp[$item['id']])) {
        $item = array_merge($item, $tmp[$item['id']]);
    }
    return $item;
}, $array1);

unset($tmp);

print_r($result);
```